# Doing Sum() on a set of anonymous type: is it possible?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, anonymous-types

If I select an anonymous type (`select new`) from a query:

```
 var smsPerGroup = from g in db.Groups
                   select new
                   {
                       GroupName = g.Name,
                       ReceivedSMS = g.Members.SelectMany(p => p.ReceivedSMS).Count()
                   };
```

It happends that I can't sum() on it:

```
int max = smsPerGroup.Max(g => g.ReceivedSMS);  // ERROR!
```

The error thrown is:
`There was an error parsing the query.`

**What is the most correct solution for this?**

I don't want to create a class to use ONLY one time, on this query.

Is it possible to have a *"not very anonymous"* type? this is: to define the type of its properties but not the type of the class itself

Something like this: (which is syntactically incorrect)

```
    ...
   select new
   {
       string GroupName = g.Name,
       int ReceivedSMS = g.Members.SelectMany(p => p.ReceivedSMS).Count()
   };
```

**Edit: the error in detail is the following**

```
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 6,Token line offset = 5,Token in error = SELECT ]

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 6,Token line offset = 5,Token in error = SELECT ]

Source Error: 


Line 159:                                      };
Line 160:
Line 161:                    int max = smsPerGroup.Max(g => g.ReceivedSMS);
```

Comment: If this is EF (or whatever the provider is), add the appropriate tags. Not all LINQ is equal. Also be sure to include the *full* message - this should include the Type for exceptions.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your queries. Could you describe your error a bit more? Is it compile of runtime error? Is there any exception thrown?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It's the message for an Exception that can be generated from an SQL Server query .. but it would be good for the OP to say as such and include the *full* details.

Comment: I added the error with detail. It is EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to materialize the query with .ToList() before calling .Sum():

```
var test = (from g in db.Groups
            select new
            {
                GroupName = g.Name,
                ReceivedSMS = g.Members.SelectMany(p => p.ReceivedSMS).Count()
            }).ToList();

var sum = test.Sum(t => t.ReceivedSMS);
```

Comment: This worked! was afraid it would delay the query but it did perfectly well